What about gravity from the edge of the observable universe?
We are aware that gravity travels with the speed of light through vaccum, and the galaxies at the edge of the observable universe are moving away from us with a speed faster than that. Would that not mean that soon, there will be no gravitational force from one of those galaxies on earth as the gravitational waves that reach us will be exhuasted, since the speed of those galaxies is increasing?

It is the gravitational waves that travel with speed of light, not gravitational force. Force does not travel at all.

since the universe is homogenous and isotropic those galaxies cancel each other out anyways due to the shell theorem, so on large there is no net gravitational pull in any direction.

What what about gravity from the edge of the observable universe?

It is the gravitational waves that travel with speed of light, not gravitational force. Force does not travel at all.

Thank you! But perhaps i didn't properly explain. But i refered to the gravitational force in the sense of the question of if the gravitational force would be annulled, which was just another way of asking if the gravitational waves reach us

@JayShinde gravitational force is not gravitational waves, it won't be annulled.

That is true. What i meant is that the gravitational force between the now out of reach galaxy and us, the rate of increase of distance between which is greater than the speed of the gravitational waves, would result in the gravitational force between them to cease to exist after the gravitational waves from the galaxy stop reaching us right?

@JayShinde no. Bodies attract each other without any gravitational waves propagating. In fact, it is very difficult to detect gravitational waves.

is not that contradictory? How can there be any gravitational force or effects without the involvement of gravitational waves

@JayShinde if two gravitating objects are stationary, then they attract each other, but there are no gravitational waves.

wouldn't that just be a stationary partial wave then, for the gravitons can reach the opposite bodies, which we are not considering to be true in the original question

@JayShinde there is no gravitational waves in a stationary system

i am not sure about that, but we can substitute waves with gravitons to get the same system, but even that suggests that there should be no gravitational effect between us and the galaxies beyond the observable universe

@JayShinde gravitons ARE quants of gravitational waves. What do you call "gravitational effect"?

@JayShinde why not take a hint?  You will not learn anything by rejecting correct answers.

@anixx There is no fundamental difference in GR between gravitational waves and gravitational force - they are both a result of the curvature of spacetime, and changes in that curvature propagate at the speed of light. If a galaxy has always been beyond the observable universe then it can have no effect on us at all, whether by gravitational waves or gravitational force.

@gandalf61 Force differs from wave in that it does not move. What you are saying is not physics. If something is not observable, it does not physically exist. But you should note that our universe is asymptotically flat, which means its mass density is uniform.

@anixx Then by your reasoning hypothetical galaxies beyond the observable universe do not exist and so certainly cannot exert any effect on us. However, if you still believe that gravitational "force" (which in GR is not really a force at all) is somehow fundamentally different from gravitational waves then you have not understood GR. Also, the mass density of the universe is not uniform in time since we know that the universe is expanding.

@gandalf61 there is cosmic complimentarity, similar to black holes. You either can interpret them existing or you can only consider only the cosmic boundary (event horizon). But there is no way in which you can interpret their energy and mass not existing.

@Anixx I see no parallels between the boundary of the observable universe and the event horizon of a black hole. "Cosmic complementarity" as I understand it means something entirely different . Do you have a reliable reference for your claim that the boundary of the observable universe is similar to the event horizon of a black hole ?

@gandalf61 there is cosmic event horizon (which is not exactly the boundary of observable universe). The cosmic horizon emits radiation, similar to Hawking radiation, at finite temperature. http://www.hartmanhep.net/topics2015/7-deSitterv2.pdf


What about gravity from the edge of the observable universe ?

Since light from galaxies outside of the observable universe cannot reach us, neither can gravitational waves (or indeed any gravitational effects) from those galaxies.

or indeed any effects
